# UITableView DidSelectRow not being called unless row is tapped multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Okay first of all I know that this question has been asked multiple times but none of these have provided me with the correct answer.

I have a TableView and when I select a row, didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not being called unless the row has been tapped somewhere between 20 - 50 times. It's weird, I have to tap the tableView furiously about 50 times before the method is called I can't workout what could be causing this strange behaviour.

Let me establish a few things:

- Yes I am calling DidSelect and not DidDeselect
- Tableview datasource and delegate are hooked up through interface builder and I am even call tableview.datasource and tableview.delegate in ViewDidLoad just to be sure.
- UserInteraction is enabled.
- All other tableView delegate methods are working exactly as expected
- I have even deleted the tableView and created it again just to be sure that I haven't changed anything that I shouldn't have.
- The tableView is made up of three sections, the top two are cells which contain UICollectionViews, they work fine and the collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath method also works fine. The third section is the one which I am having trouble with and the only section which needs to handle tableView row selection

Here are my tableView methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (hasFinishedQuery == NO) {
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return 3;
    }
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 2) {
        return quickLinksArray.count;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        NSDictionary *dic = [quickLinksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         NSString *cellidentifier = [dic objectForKey:@"title"];

        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];

        if (!cell)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier];
        }
        NSNumber *countNumber = [dic valueForKey:@"count"];
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
        [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", countNumber]];
        label.layer.cornerRadius = 18;
        label.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

        return cell;

    }
    else{
        static NSString *cellidentifier = @"cellidentifier";

        TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];

        if (!cell)
        {
            cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier];
        }

        return cell;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(TableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section != 2) {
        [self insertDatasourceAndDelegateForCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath andCellType:NO];
    }
}

- (void) insertDatasourceAndDelegateForCell:(TableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath andCellType:(BOOL)cellType
{
    if (indexPath.section != 2) {
        [cell setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:self index:indexPath.section andCellType:cellType];
        NSInteger index = cell.collectionViewHorizontal.tag;

        CGFloat horizontalOffset = [self.contentOffsetDictionary[[@(index) stringValue]] floatValue];
        [cell.collectionViewHorizontal setContentOffset:CGPointMake(horizontalOffset, 0)];
    }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"Cell Tapped");
    selectedDictionary = [quickLinksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToListView" sender:self];
}
```

If you want to see any other code just let me know,

Hope you can help,
Shayne

Comment: Where's your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method? Is your problem will all sections of your table view? Do your cell's have subviews that may be stealing the touch events?

Comment: @rmaddy I added the code for didSelectRowAtIndexPath, the cell has only three subviews, 2 labels and 1 imageView. Nothing that should interfere with the selection. The problem is only with this section. The other two sections only contain 1 collectionView each. The collectionViews are displayed as they are intended to be and the selection for them works perfectly.

Comment: @rmaddy I even tried removing all of the subviews from the cells and displaying them blank and even still they could not be selected unless they were furiously tapped

Comment: It's really strange (and a bad idea) to put collection views in a table view cell. As a test, narrow your table view down to just one section using the cells giving you the issue. It will be interesting to see if removing all of the collection views from the table view clear up the issue.

Comment: Okay, I solved it, such a rookie error! In interface builder I had set the tableViewCell class to the class that I was using for the cells which contained the collectionViews, I changed the cell class back to a UITableViewCell and the cell selection now works as intended... Can't believe I have spent so many hours trying to work something out that was so simple.

Comment: Have you checked tableviewcell selection style...if it is none selection will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay simple error. I had created a sub class of UITableViewCell which was designed to be used for the cells which contained my collectionViews. For some reason I had all of the tableViewCells set to that subclass, even the ones which were not supposed to be. In interface builder I changed the cells class back to the original UITableViewCell and now it handles selection as intended.

Lessons I have learnt from this:

1. I had named the a subclass of UITableViewCell "TableViewCell". This was a dumb move as it is too similar to UITableViewCell and made this error hard to spot.
2. When creating the cells I just duplicated cells that I had already created rather then dropping new cells into the view. If I had of just dropped new cells into the view instead of taking the easy way this would not have happened.